# Preload content of a remote: true link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `link_to` helper ajaxified with `remote: true`.

The content that the link renders is computational heavy, so I would like to preload that content such that clicking on the link renders the content instantanesously.

How would I go about achieveing this? If at all possible.

**Update**
I would love to have it load asynchronously, i.e. the current page loads and gets displayed first in it entirety, and then the content of the linked url is preloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Put the content in some hidden html elements like span or div.

```
<span id="mycontent" style="display:none">Some content</span>
```

and when you have to display just pick the content in span

```
$("span#mycontent").html();
```

and use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To have it load after finishing the main page, use this Javascript snippet (jQuery flavor):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: "<%= your_path_to_action %>",
             data: { param1: <%= your_param  %> },
             success: function(response) { $('#hidden_div').html(response); }
    }); 
});
```

This code fires the AJAX request once the page has finished loading. The `success` handler then puts the response in a hidden element like techvineet correctly suggested. Use the button to execute another JS function for copying the hidden div's content (or making it visible)